# How to change NotifyIcon's context menu in explorer.exe?

Tags: c++, explorer, notifyicon, dll-injection, easyhook

I want to extend the default Speakers notificon's (tray icon) right-click context menu with a new item. Also, I want to handle the mouseclick using C++.

**Illustration**

[image]

**What I know so far**

I learned how to dll-inject using *CreateRemoteThread()*, because I think that's the way to go. My problem is: what to do inside the injected dll? For example, how to access the NotifyIcon object?

Maybe it is possible with a simple Windows API call, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Ultimately someone is going to call TrackPopupMenu().  I guess you could hook that, copy the menu, insert your item, then call the real TrackPopupMenu() with TPM_RETURNCMD.  If the ID is yours you can handle it; if the id is not yours then you can return back to the caller.  However, this is a pretty hairy approach if you ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Luke for the hint. I got it working using [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/). I chose it, because it also supports 64-bit dll-inject.

**DLL to inject:**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using EasyHook;
namespace InjectDLL
    {
    public class Main : EasyHook.IEntryPoint
    {
        LocalHook CreateTrackPopupMenuExHook;
        public Main(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext){}
        public void Run(RemoteHooking.IContext InContext)
        {
            try
            {
                CreateTrackPopupMenuExHook = LocalHook.Create(
                    LocalHook.GetProcAddress("user32.dll", "TrackPopupMenuEx"),
                    new DTrackPopupMenuEx(TrackPopupMenuEx_Hooked),
                    this);
                CreateTrackPopupMenuExHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool AppendMenu(IntPtr hMenu, long uFlags, int uIDNewItem, string lpNewItem);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern IntPtr TrackPopupMenuEx(
            IntPtr hMenu,
            uint fuFlags,
            int x,
            int y,
            IntPtr hwnd,
            IntPtr lptpm);

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        delegate IntPtr DTrackPopupMenuEx(
            IntPtr hMenu,
            uint fuFlags,
            int x,
            int y,
            IntPtr hwnd,
            IntPtr lptpm);

        const long MF_STRING = 0x00000000L;
        const long MF_SEPARATOR = 0x00000800L;

        static IntPtr TrackPopupMenuEx_Hooked(
            IntPtr hMenu,
            uint fuFlags,
            int x,
            int y,
            IntPtr hwnd,
            IntPtr lptpm)
        {
            IntPtr returnValue = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                    //Separator
                    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, null);
                    //New menu item
                    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, 40010, "TestMenuItem");
                    //call the default procedure
                    returnValue = TrackPopupMenuEx(hMenu, fuFlags, x, y, hwnd, lptpm);
                    //our menu item is selected
                    if (returnValue == (IntPtr)40010)
                    {
                        /* CODE HERE */
                        returnValue = IntPtr.Zero;
                    }
                    return returnValue;
            }
            catch
            {
                return;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```